# importScripts fails for Safari web extension

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

I'm porting a working v3 chrome extension to Safari on MacOS. In my background (service worker) script I call

`self.importScripts("Platform.js");`

which should load said JavaScript file. It's in the same folder as the script that calls it.

But this fails in Safari (not chrome) with the error:

> Failed to load resource: unsupported URL safari-web-extension://FE580C4D-9931-4639-ABF9-...../Platform.js

(dots substituted for the last hex digits). In the manifest I have the lines:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": ["Platform.js"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    },...
```

I'm following the instructions for [converting a web extension to Safari](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions/converting_a_web_extension_for_safari). I'm running MacOS Monterey, Safari 15.5.

Any pointers as to what I might need to try would be appreciated. I thought of statically importing the code but it's not a JavaScript module.

Comment: Also running into this. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I tried several ways of turning the imported JavaScript code into a module so that it could be statically imported, but without success. If anyone knows a way to do that in the context of an extension, I'd like to hear it. The option I'm going to try next is the same extension but using manifest v2 instead of v3 (obviating the dynamic import).

Comment: Hm, using mv2 worked fine and is good enough for my purposes but is obviously kind of dissatisfying for authors of extensions that want to publish on Chrome and Safari. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: importScripts is supported in Safari starting from version 16.3 (https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_workerglobalscope_importscripts). One way to overcome the issue is to queue all the background modules into a unique file.js. There are several ready-to-use tools on the net to do this (e.g. https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) or you can do it manually by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I haven't worked on this problem for a while. When I upgraded Safari to 16.4 just now and tried again, it just worked

Answer (score 0):

Had the same or similar issue with manifest v3 and safari 16.1.  First, be sure that all the code (.js, .html, .css) are included in the build for code signing on "Build Phases"::

[Build Phases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLI5i.png)

Next, I was trying to use module support.  In the manifest.json, i removed the :

```
"background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js",
        "type" : "module"
    },
```

and replaced it with:

```
"background": {
    "page" : "background.html"
},
```

the background.html then is a simple:

```
<script type="module" src="background.js"></script>
```

the background.js then uses an import on the first line as:

```
import * as common from "./common.js";
```